# URL helper in JavaScript

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I'm using jQuery Lightbox for my image gallery.
The URL for the button image is '`../../Content/Lightbox/lightbox-btn-next.gif`'
That works fine if my URL is '`localhost/Something1/Somtehing2`' 
If I use another route like '`localhost/Something1/Something2/Something3`' then URL to button images is incorrect. 
Can I use `Url.Action()` inside .js files? 
This is how I call .js files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js") %>"></script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use Url.Action() inside .js files. But you can define global variable and use it in you js file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var imageUrl = "<%= ... %>";

</script>
```

Answer (score 10):

I put the following in my master page, which accomplishes much the same thing as @Url.Content('~/path'):

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function UrlContent(path) {
        return '@Url.Content("~/")' + path.replace(/^\//, ''); 
    }
</script>
```

When my master page is compiled and served up this translates into a javascript function that applies my site root to the path.  Works great.  The path.replace regex simply removes a leading slash if there is one since @Url.Content("~/") has a terminating slash.

Comment: Thanks @matt. Excellent idea and works pretty well here.

Answer (score 2):

Just put `@Url.Content(@"~/some paths")` into single quotes such as this:

```
'@Url.Content(@"~/some paths")'
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to pull the URLs from a tags 'href's or form 'action's - or some other element that makes sense.

```
<img class="_click" src="<%= Url.Content("~/my/image.png") %>" alt="Click" />
```

And in my javascript (double check this on jQuery, I am not sure if it's the exact syntax.):

```
var url = $('._click').attr('href');
// To pass these to your plugin as options
// see lightbox source for a full list
$('a').lightBox({ imageLoading : url })
```

Another slightly less preferred option is to add your settings on top of your file:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
    $('a').lightBox({ imageLoading : <%= Url.Content("~/my/image.png") %> })
//]]></script>
```

I said 'less preferred' because this approach mixes markup and code.

Yet another approach (which needs a lot of tidy up) is to serve you js file from a controller:

```
public ActionResult GetFileContent(string filename)
{
    // important: make sure to control the path for security
    var path = Server.MapPath("~/Scripts/" + filename);
    var content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);

    // Use some kind of template convention
    content = content.Replace("{{IMAGE_PATH}}", Url.Content(@"~/my/image.png"));

    var bytes = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(content);
    return new FileContentResult(bytes, "text/javascript");
}
```