# url.content(...) like method in jquery or javascript?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Url helper in java script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235979/url-helper-in-java-script)

Url.Content(...) asp.net mvc helper method returns equivalent absolute URL. I'm searching for a method in jquery or javascript that works like this...

because, I want to separat javascript code into a file (.js) and you know that file doesn't supports Url.Content(...) inside javscript code....

url(...) method of jquery not works like Url.Content()

**Updated: 22 Jan 2011**

I have a workaround:

In the .cshtml file, I created a ‘**GetPath**’ function that returns absolute path including domain name and can be accessible inside any .js file.

Include following code in any ASP.NET MVC view (.cshtml or .aspx or .vbhtml):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var fullPath = '@HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme://@HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority';
    function GetPath(url) {
        return fullPath + url;
    }
</script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/JavaScriptFile.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And the code inside any javascript file.

```
$(function () {
    alert(GetPath('/Content/Site.css'));
});
```

The result is: http://www.yourDomain.com/Content/Site.css
or  localhost:1234/Content/Site.css    >> Visual Cassini server

You just need to replace `@Url.Content("")` with `GetPath('')` in any .js file.

http://muaz-khan.blogspot.com/2012/02/absolute-or-relative-url-issues-and.html

Comment: You should put your workaround in an answer in stead of in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [ASP.NET MVC JavaScript Routing](http://weblogs.asp.net/zowens/archive/2010/12/20/asp-net-mvc-javascript-routing.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Also,

there's a great example here:

[do you write your JavaScript in a ASP.NET MVC view ... or in a separate JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624626/do-you-write-your-javascript-in-a-asp-net-mvc-view-or-in-a-separate-javascrip/4625478#4625478)

that uses the data attributes on jquery to store arbitary objects for exactly the purpose that you propose. Check out the accepted answer for the full details.