# Concatenate string for @Url.Content with in the Underscore.js template

Tags: javascript, templates, underscore.js

I am unable to prepare string url for @Url.Content method.

Here is my block of code from Underscore template

```
 <%  var imgId = "~/Content/images/" +pocket.get('imageId'); %>   
        <div class="image1">       
            <% alert(imgId); %>         
            <img src= "@Url.Content("+<% imgId %>+")"  alt="Assigned Details" />
```

I'll pass the "imageId" through pocket object.

I tried using following approach as well. Getting compilation error for imgId variable

`<img src= "<%= @Url.Content(string.Format("~/Content/Images/{0}", imgId)) %>" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:** 
Finally I figured out the solution from another thread: [Call js function from underscore template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745940/url-content-like-method-in-jquery-or-javascript)
1. js function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var fullPath = '@HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme://@HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority';
function GetPath(url) {
    return fullPath + url;
}
```

2. call js from your code: `<img src= '<%= GetPath(imgId) %>' alt="Med Assigned" />`

Answer (score 0):

You use `<% ... %>` to evaluate some JavaScript in an Underscore template but you use `<%= ... %>` if you want the output to end up in the result; from the [fine manual](http://underscorejs.org/#template):

> Template functions can both interpolate variables, using `<%= … %>`, as well as execute arbitrary JavaScript code, with `<% … %>`.

You're looking to interpolate the `imgId` value into the result so you want this:

```
<img src= "@Url.Content("+<%= imgId %>+")"  alt="Assigned Details" />
```

Simplified Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/9gyKC/

Presumably `@Url.Content` is something that gets run on the server to produce a `src` attribute for a given resource. If that's the case then you'll have to rethink how this works; the `<%= ... %>` stuff happens in the browser *after* `@Url.Content` has been executed so it will be too late when the Underscore template runs. Your note about an `imgId` error with this:

```
<img src= "<%= @Url.Content(string.Format("~/Content/Images/{0}", imgId)) %>" />
```

supports this theory. Your server code doesn't know what `imgId` is, only the client-side JavaScript does.

Comment: Even though it prints out, if you include inside <img>/src tag it's not picking the value. src= + <%= imgId %> +

Comment: @RameshTamma: What is `@Url.Content` and when does it get executed? Does it get executed on the server?

Comment: I am trying to resolve the URL using @Url.Content, it's Razor syntax and we can embed with in the client syntax.

Comment: @RameshTamma: But `@Url.Content` and `<%= imgId %>` are being evaluated in different places at different times so you can't mix them like that. The Razor stuff is evaluated before Underscore gets to the template.